# Using Angular with Breeze and OData

Tags: angularjs, breeze

how can i config breeze to work with Angular and OData?

i set

```
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("modelLibrary", "backingStore", true);
```

but i need also to set

```
dataService: "OData"
```

but the setproperty is obselete

Comment: i have used breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("modelLibrary", "backingStore", true);
    breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstances({ dataService: "OData" });

Comment: but i get error of - Uncaught Error: Module name "OData" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 Breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("dataService", "OData");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstances({ dataService: "OData" });
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("modelLibrary", "backingStore", true);
```

Comment: Hi, happy to see you found your answer, but it's helpful to add more than only a few lines of code - perhaps some text explaining how you found it or why this is needed.